# Expanding integer-sequence template-param in compile time

Tags: c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I am a bit uncertain about how to achieve variadic-expansion in compile time.
Consider the below use-case where I'd like to figure out the index of the max-element in the sequence:

```
template<A>
struct doSomething {
  static constexpr int getIndexOfMaxValue() {
    // recursive variadic expansion
  }

  static constexpr int value = getIndexOfMaxValue();
}

int main() {
   std::cout << doSomething<std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3>::value <<std::endl;
}
```

Can someone kindly help me explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename T, T... Vals, size_t... Is>
constexpr int getIndexOfMaxValueHelper(
    std::integer_sequence<T, Vals...>,
    std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  constexpr T max_val = std::max({Vals...});
  constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(Is);
  return std::min({(Vals == max_val ? Is : N)...});
}

template <typename A>
struct doSomething {
  static constexpr int getIndexOfMaxValue() {
    return getIndexOfMaxValueHelper(A{}, std::make_index_sequence<A::size()>{});
  }

  static constexpr int value = getIndexOfMaxValue();
};

int main() {
   std::cout << doSomething<std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3>>::value <<std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/aKhdr8)

Comment: Thanks, this looks good.
Noob question: I want to ensure the `::value` is available during compile time. Whats the right way for me to figure out that it is in this case?

Comment: See if `int arr[doSomething<...>::value]` or `template <int n> struct S {}; S<doSomething<...>::value>` compiles.

Comment: Thats very helpful.
I still have trouble understanding how the `min((Vals == max_val ? Is : N)...})` variadic expansion takes place. Do you mind elaborating on it please?

Comment: There are two sequences running in parallel - `Vals...` with the original values, and `Is...` that are simply `0, 1, 2, ...`, as manufactured by `make_index_sequence`. So `(Vals == max_val ? Is : N)...` produces a sequence that, in position `i`, has `i` if `Val` at that position is equal to `max_val`, and `N` (a number larger than any valid `i`) otherwise. So e.g. it could be `N, 1, N, N, 4, N`. Then `min` over that sequence just picks the first (leftmost) position where `Val == max_val`